# Enabling https after successful authentication mean.js

Tags: angularjs, https, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm working on an application using the mean.js framework. I have successfully managed to get facebook and local passport auth working. What I'm looking for a way to do is use https instead of http after the user has successfully logged in. I havent been able to find something useful on this so far.

Kindly note I'm new to working with mean.js, angular and express.

Comment: Did you check this, https://github.com/meanjs/mean#running-with-tls-ssl ?